# Syntax for passing result of boolean evaluation in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, boolean

I'm not sure if this is an angular-centric question or just plain old JS syntax question. I'm obviously getting rusty as this feels like a dumb question but...

I'm trying to pass in the result of an if/then statement as an array variable in my angular template. Example:

```
<div my-angular-component [variables]="{title: 'hello world', isSelected: true}"></div>
```

The catch is that instead of passing in the boolean 'true' I want to pass in the result of some logic so it looks something like this:

```
<div my-angular-component [variables]="{title: 'hello world', isSelected: if(a=b){pass in true}else{pass in false}}"></div>
```

Can that be done directly in the array itself?

Comment: `return true`/`return false`? Or just assign the result of the test?

Comment: Also you should do comparison here `if( a === b)` not assignment `if( a = b)`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use either boolean algebra :

```
isSelected: a === b
```

Or if you want more advanced values, a ternary :

```
isSelected: a === b ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: ***Side note:-*** Or you can also do `+( a === b )` if you want values

Comment: @CodeManiac that was an exemple to show how you can send something else than a boolean through a ternary. But sure, in this case that works.